# Как сделать, чтобы пользователь не мог сменить emaill на существующий в базе mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

есть код на node js, есть форма смены профиля и нужно чтобы введенный email сранивал есть ли такой в базе данных и в случае если есть, выдавал ошибку status(400), уже готова две функции связанные с базой данных

```
exports.getAll = async () => {
    const results = await promisify(db.query).bind(db)('SELECT * FROM users');
    return results;
}

exports.getById = async (id) => {
   const results = await promisify(db.query).bind(db)('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', id);

   if(!results.length)
       return 0;

   return results[0];
}

const userEmail = parseInt(req.body.email);
const users = await this.getAll();
```

Как реализовать?

Comment: Можно делать это на уровне клиента - запрашивать количество записей с введённым e-mail, и давать отлуп, если оно ненулевое. Можно и на уровне сервера - сделать поле e-mail уникальным и ловить ошибку нарушения ограничения уникальности. Второе - и логичнее, и проще.

Comment: Можете примерно описать как сделать на уровне сервера?

Comment: Создать в структуре уникальный индекс по этому полю. Только не надо спрашивать, как это делать в node.js - я понятия не имею... предполагаю, что где-то в модели нужно указать, что поле уникально (но не факт, что фреймворк не начнёт это контролировать программно...).

Comment: @Akina такой себе вариант. Это скорее безопасность, сделать поле в БД типа required

Comment: @AlexandrSolopov `required` - это в терминах SQL `NOT NULL`. Который к уникальности никакого отношения не имеет. И с моей точки зрения клиентский контроль вместо штатного integrity check - это и есть "так себе" решение.

Comment: @Akina извините, я перепутал с UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

При изменении данных сделайте запрос в БД следующего вида:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', email
```

Допустим:

```js
const results = await promisify(db.query).bind(db)('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', email);
```

Далее проверьте, если нашлись пользователи, тогда выкинем ошибку

```js
if (results.length) {
 // выкидываем ошибку
}
```

Если всё ок, то далее описывается ваша логика и сохранение новых данных...

Comment: А можно ли как-то реализовать через получение всех пользователей и функций filter или find

Comment: @Hellius быстрее всего будет отдать запрос с ограниченной выборкой именно СУБД, а не получать всех пользователей. Под капотом там индексы, оптимизации и тд, то есть поиск будет работать намного быстрее, чем если вы получите к примеру миллиард пользователей и ваш код на node.js будет делать поиск/фильтрацию

Comment: А все же можете описать как сделать через find или filter, просто хочу понять как на практике будут работать именно эти функции. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Hellius сделал новый ответ

Answer (score 0):

По просьбе автора.

**filter:**

```js
// допустим получили список пользователей
let users = [
    {id: 1, email: "a"},
    {id: 2, email: "b"},
    {id: 3, email: "c"},
];

// что ищем
const candidateEmail = "b";

users = users.filter((v) => {
    return v.email === candidateEmail;
});

if (users.length) {
    console.error('Данный email уже занят');
} else {
    console.log('Всё ок');
}
```

**find:**

```js
// допустим получили список пользователей
let users = [
    {id: 1, email: "a"},
    {id: 2, email: "b"},
    {id: 3, email: "c"},
];

// что ищем
const candidateEmail = "b";

const exists = users.find((v) => {
    if (v.email === candidateEmail) return true;
});
if (exists) {
    console.error('Данный email уже занят');
} else {
    console.log('Всё ок');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое